# failure to install many commands in ubuntu-14

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, command

Being that hapless user who straggled with "bash-shell" (I finally decided to install tshell instead -- too much trouble fixing all the old scripts), I run into another trouble: my ubuntu-14 doesn't have 
**acroread, ratfor90, latex**, 
and many others commands. I first was looking for them by using

```
dpkg -s <command>
```

and after getting a negative result (which as I know by now, doesn't mean much), was still trying to install a package by using

```
sudo apt-get install <command>
```

-- with negative results for the command I've mentioned. I was successful for some commands (such as "gv", "gfortran", and some others).

What am I to do now? I never was good on installing commands by package downloading from the internet. Besides, there will be too many of them.

Comment: If you want help solving your errors, you need to mention what they error as precisely as possible.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install acroread
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package acroread

Comment: Try following: http://askubuntu.com/a/89129

Comment: The packages sometimes do not have names that corresponds to actual commands. "latex" may be found in "texlive-latex-base", for example. Others may be found in non-standard repositories.

Comment: @Kusalananda : as it was time, you put your finger right on the right point -- extended name. Furthermore, following your lead , I found that i can actually use even a wild card, in this case it was like   dpkg-query -l '*latex*'

Comment: @Kusalananda : as it was the last time with 'bash-shell", you put your finger right on the right spot -- extended name. Furthermore, following your lead , I found that i can actually use even a wild card, in this case it was like   dpkg-query -l '*latex*' ! Anyway,  both requests worked in my old tabletop comp, but not in my new laptop; looks like I've got a very limited distribution package. I am wandering if there is a simple way to just transfer my "texlive-latex-base" from my tabletop to my laptop...

Comment: As a side note, there is no "ubuntu-14", there is only Ubuntu with the releases 14.04 and 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dpkg -S` will only tell you about files in packages that are already installed. You need something that will tell you about files in packages that you do not have installed. `apt-file` is such a tool.

You need to install it, `apt-get install apt-file`, then `apt-file update`, then `apt-file search latex`.

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/latex 
latex-mk: /usr/bin/latex-mk
latex209-bin: /usr/bin/latex209
latex2html: /usr/bin/latex2html
latex2rtf: /usr/bin/latex2png
latex2rtf: /usr/bin/latex2rtf
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-cvs
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-fast
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-git
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-hg
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-rcs
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-svn
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexdiff-vc
latexdiff: /usr/bin/latexrevise
latexdraw: /usr/bin/latexdraw
latexila: /usr/bin/latexila
latexmk: /usr/bin/latexmk
latexml: /usr/bin/latexml
latexml: /usr/bin/latexmlc
latexml: /usr/bin/latexmlfind
latexml: /usr/bin/latexmlmath
latexml: /usr/bin/latexmlpost
liblatex-decode-perl: /usr/bin/latex2utf8
liblatex-driver-perl: /usr/bin/latex2dvi
liblatex-driver-perl: /usr/bin/latex2pdf
liblatex-driver-perl: /usr/bin/latex2ps
liblatex-encode-perl: /usr/bin/latex-encode
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latex-git-log
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latex2man
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latexdef
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latexfileversion
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latexindent
texlive-extra-utils: /usr/bin/latexpand
texlive-latex-base: /usr/bin/latex
tth-common: /usr/bin/latex2gif
```

The package you are looking for is second to last in this list, namely `texlive-latex-base`. Then you just need to do `apt-get install texlive-latex-base`. This is one of the TeX Live packages. Though for TeX Live, you're probably better off just installing the `texlive` metapackage. Namely `apt-get install texlive`.

I don't think `ratfor90` is available on Debian, at least. I'm not sure about Ubuntu. And as far as `acroread` goes, give either `okular` or `evince` a try. I use `okular`.

Comment: my great thanks!  It was hugely helpful! I did it, and now I've got latex installed. About ratfor90: I do have it on my old computer running ubuntu (issue 12); my friend installed it, but he moved by now. Is there any way how I can transfer ratfor90 from my old comp to my new laptop? (be aware please that I am a dumb user; but I see clearly that you have experience talking to the guys like me..:-)

Comment: Dear Faheem -- I just installed okular,  it works, but keeps reporting a lot of errors or some differences, although the output seems to be OK. Still, acroread was nice, and I always prefer to have some backup tools...

Comment: @AlKap It looks like acroread is still available on www.deb-multimedia.org, if you really want to install it. Though I don't recommend it - it's unmaintained.

Comment: Is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ratfor the ratfor you had in mind?

Comment: Faheem, no, not that one (the one you pointed out is an "old" ratfor that worked for fortran77, What I am looking for, is usually called ratfor90, designed specifically for the fortran90 (and beyond), in particular with gfortran. Most of all, it knows how to do dynamic allocations, and how to work with "objects". It is a great tool, and used by now by many people who use contemporary fortrans...

Comment: Faheem, speaking of acroread, I just followed all the suggestion by Julia @GAD3R (see our exchange on answer 2), including all the updates (see her editing) , and got a fully functional tool; so by now I have both okular and acroread, which is exactly what I wanted.. I do understand that acroread is not supported anymore, but this doesn't bother me a slightest. I am myself a dinosaur, and if I have it running for a few more years as is, it is more than I need... I do my research and sometimes simply need two tools having different properties, so when one is not good, another one may help...

Answer (score 0):

To install `acroread` , Download the latest version from [here](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/) and install it :

```
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Install the missing libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

**NB** Acroread is marked as [deprecated](https://en.opensuse.org/Adobe_Reader):

> As of mid-2014, Adobe no longer publishes any GNU/Linux version of Adobe Reader, and has pulled the latest version (Adobe Reader 9) from its download sites.

**Edit**

Enable the Canonical Partner:

```
sed -i "/^# deb .*partner/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list 
apt-get update
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a sort of integral solution to my problem (too many commands are missing...)?

Comment: Please edit you answer by adding the output of failed commands.

Comment: I am a bit confused; the site you are citing is on Chinese Adobe Fonts...

Comment: @AlKap:  You are not forced to try anything you are advised to but don't be surprised if no one magically installs the programs on your computer.  This answer looks very valid and quite resembles the link I referred you to in my comment.  The note on the fact that it is **deprecated** should also tell you to look for an alternate solution.

Comment: @GAD3R: I don't know how it came to be viewed as deprecated, for I am greatly grateful for any advice I get at this site, including your thoughtful  and  so friendly advises.

Comment: @GAD3R:  please disregard my last comment-to-your-comment; I simply got a wrong impression of your reference to "deprecated" -- I realized now that you talked about  Linux not being supported by Adobe Reader...

Comment: The reference is updated

Comment: @GAD3R: I've just Installed  the missing libraries proposed by you in your last update. and now acroread works beautifully,, without any hitches. Thanks a lot!